# WPF ComboBox binding ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I'm a beginner on WPF and trying to bind the Items of a ComboBox to an ObservableCollection

I used this code:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="comboBinding2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cmbTest" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cmbContent}" Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
public MainWindow()
{
    cmbTest.ItemsSource = cmbContent;
    cmbContent.Add("test 1");
    cmbContent.Add("test 2");

    InitializeComponent();
}

public ObservableCollection<string> cmbContent { get; set; }
```

I don't get any errors on this Code until I try to debug, it throws the error:

TargetInvocationError

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your current implementation. As others have stated, your list is currently `NULL`, and the `DataContext` of the Window is not set.

Though, I would recommend (especially since you just started using WPF) is learning to do the binding the more 'correct' way, using `MVVM`.

See the simplified example below:

First, you want to set the `DataContext` of your `Window`. This will allow the `XAML` to 'see' the properties within your `ViewModel`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Next, simply set up a `ViewModel` class that will contain all of the `Window's` binding elements, such as:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> CmbContent { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        CmbContent = new ObservableCollection<string>
        {
            "test 1", 
            "test 2"
        };
    }
}
```

Lastly, update your `XAML` so that the binding path matches the collection:

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Width="200"
          VerticalAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
          x:Name="cmbTest"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CmbContent}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This works fine, but how can I add an other string to CmbContent from the MainWindow???

Comment: do you want to add a string real-time, or have the combobox include additional strings?

Comment: I want to add a string real-time

Comment: Okay, real-time based on a user interface control (i.e., text box + button)? or behind the scenes? what mechanism are you looking for

Comment: I've found a way to do this _ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = vm;
            vm.cmbContent.Add("test 3");_
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
   public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        cmbContent=new ObservableCollection<string>();
        cmbContent.Add("test 1");
        cmbContent.Add("test 2");
        cmbTest.ItemsSource = cmbContent;

    }
    public ObservableCollection<string> cmbContent { get; set; }
```

The code above don't use any binding, that's mean using it there no need to bind the `Combobox's` `ItemSource`, if you wan't to use binding you need to

**First**: Set the DataContext from the CodeBehind (ViewModel) using :

```
this.DataContext=this;
```

or from the Xaml:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

**Second** : use the Binding in the ItemSource Just like you did `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=cmbContent}"` you may also considere using `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface if you want to Notify the UI in case of any changes in a property

Answer (score 1):

`cmbContent` is null because you never set it to anything. I'm guessing the error is actually a `NullReferenceException`, but it is showing up as `TargetInvocationException` because it is in the constructor of a view.

Also, you're setting the `ItemsSource` of the `ComboBox` twice (once in the binding, once in the constructor). You don't need to do that. Pick one. Your binding won't work the way it is written (because the `DataContext` isn't set) so you should either go with doing it in code, or set up the `DataContext` (as suggested by Nadia).