# ComboBox Static value binding in mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

I have one **comboBox** with  value [ days,weeks,months,years]

```
   <ComboBox Width="130" Margin="0,10,0,16" ItemsSource="{Binding PeriodCollection }" 
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDuration }" 
               Text=""  DisplayMemberPath="Name" />
```

Beside comboBox , I have one Textbox. If user selects "weeks" from comboBox and put value 2 in textbox, in database I have to save 2*7 = 14 [ days].

To do this functionality I have created period collection.

```
 public class Period : BaseObject
    {
        private string name;
        public string Name 
        { 
            get { return name; } 
            set { name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } 
        }

        private int numberOfDays;
        /// <summary>
        /// number of days in period
        /// </summary>
        public int NumberOfDays 
        { 
            get { return numberOfDays; } 
            set { numberOfDays = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } 
        }        

        public Period(string perdioName, int numberOfDayInPeriod)
        {
            Name = perdioName;
            NumberOfDays = numberOfDayInPeriod;
        }
    }
}
 public static class PeriodManager
{
    private static ObservableImmutableList<Period> periodCollection;
    /// <summary>
    /// return a collection of time period in days        /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Days, Week,Month, year</returns>
    public static ObservableImmutableList<Period> GetPeriodCollection()
    {
        if (periodCollection == null)
        {
            periodCollection = new ObservableImmutable.ObservableImmutableList<Entities.Period>();
            periodCollection.Add(new Period("Days", 1));
            periodCollection.Add(new Period("Week", 7));
            periodCollection.Add(new Period("Month", 30));
            periodCollection.Add(new Period("Year", 365));
        }
        return periodCollection;
    }

    /// you can create method can return a period from a day number...

}
```

Now in my viewModel I am trying to implement a method which will return days.

```
private ObservableImmutableList<Period> periodCollection;
public ObservableImmutableList<Period> PeriodCollection { get { return periodCollection; } set { periodCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }

private Period selectedDuration;
public Period SelectedDuration { get { return selectedDuration; } set { selectedDuration = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } }

private void GetPeriod()
{
    PeriodCollection =  PeriodManager.GetPeriodCollection();
    //here I need to write logic to merge from both values [ txtBox+combox]
}
```

But I am confused with -

while saving how I'll merge with textbox value with returned value of combobox days [ if entered 2 in textbox and selected week in comobox, i need value 14]

Please help me with this in wpf mvvm concept. I tried in web but was not able to find any in mvvm.

Comment: You don't need to add `ComboBoxItem`s in xaml if you are binding to `ItemsSource`. In MVVM you would normally have all collections defined in ViewModel/Model and view simply bind to them.

Comment: itemsource code is blank right now with "_Collection" I need complete solution, what logic is best for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF ComboBox binding ItemsSource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373643/wpf-combobox-binding-itemssource). See accepted answer for an example of `ComboBox.ItemsSource` binding. Or maybe you want to [bind to static property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/936304/1997232).

Comment: itemsource edited, check. it was never my problem. problem is with merging both values and saving.

Comment: which is the ViewModel of your View right now?

Comment: You can bind `TextBox.Text` to `double Number` property and `ComboBox.SelectedItem` to `Period SelectedPeriod` property. Then you need a command (or simply call some method from setters of those properties): in this command do `Number * SelectedPeriod.NumberOfDays`.

Comment: @ehsan viewmodel code added..... check

Comment: @sintar ok. I'll try this.

Comment: Side note... what's an ObservableImmutableList, and exactly what's the point of its existence?  If it's immutable, why would it have any change notification???  I feel dizzy.  Someone, bring me an alcohol.

Comment: it is our own defined class library in our project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View Model you need to add another property that will be bind with the Text Box so that you can have access to value of **TextBox** as well in your View Model, so first of all add a new property in your View Model :

```
private ObservableImmutableList<Period> periodCollection;
public ObservableImmutableList<Period> PeriodCollection 
{ 
   get { return periodCollection; } 
   set { periodCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } 
}

private Period selectedDuration;
public Period SelectedDuration 
{ 
  get { return selectedDuration; } 
  set { selectedDuration = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } 
}

private int _providedNumber;
public int ProvidedNumber
{ 
  get { return _providedNumber; } 
  set { _providedNumber= value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); } 
}

private void GetPeriod()
{
    PeriodCollection =  PeriodManager.GetPeriodCollection();
    //here I need to write logic to merge from both values [ txtBox+combox]
}
```

and in xaml sepcify binding of TextBox with the property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ProvidedNumber}"></TextBox>
```

Now in `GetPeriod` method you can have both value and do whatever is business reuqirements :

```
private void GetPeriod()
{
    PeriodCollection =  PeriodManager.GetPeriodCollection();

    var value = _providedNumber * selectedDuration.NumberOfDays;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it'll work. Once I implement I'll let you know.